# Insert relational models laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, eloquent

I am new to eloquent for laravel 4 and i can't quite figure out on how to make and save related models.

Table Messages: `id | user | message | parent`

For example:

```
class Message extends Eloquent {

   public function user(){
      return $this->belongs_to('User', 'id');
   }

   public function child(){
      return $this->hasMany('Message', 'parent');
   }

   public function parent(){
      return $this->belongs_to('Message', 'id')
   }

 }
```

So if you have a conversation you have a message, this message may or may not have a child or a parent and always has a user which made the message. So if i want to save a conversation this way, how would i do this?

For example, i have to following conversation:

> ***John (1) says:*** Hi all! 
>   ***Mark (3) responds:*** Hey there! 
>   ***Hans (4) responds:*** Hi john 
>   ***Peter(2) responds:*** Goodmorning.

Now i am john and i would like to save this conversation as below:

```
  id  |  user  |    message    | parent
========================================
1     | 1      | Hi, All!      | NULL
2     | 3      | Hey there!    | 1
3     | 4      | Hi john       | 1
4     | 2      | Goodmorning.  | 1
```

I can save them all separately but i figure there has to be a better way than below:

```
$parent = NULL;

foreach($messages as $message){
   $model = new Message;
      $model->user = $message['user'];
      $model->message = $message['value'];
      if(!is_null($parent)){
         $model->parent = $parent;
      }
   $model->save();
   if(is_null($parent)){
      $parent = $model->id;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial problem I saw was that you are saying that the message's parent is always itself, you need to specify an additional unsigned integer to relate on. Here's one example:

```
public function parent(){
    return $this->belongs_to('Message', 'parent_id')
}
```

You need to use that same `'parent_id'` for the children as well:

```
public function children(){
    return $this->hasMany('Message', 'parent_id');
}
```

Comment: Going over my old stack overflow questions, noticed I never responded or accepted your answer. My apologies for this and thanks for your response. Accepted your answer.